# Crontab cron job will not run with url with parameter

Tags: curl, cron, cron-task

```
38  17  5   11  *    /usr/bin/sudo -u www /usr/bin/curl -sS "http://123.com/index.php?email=1&test=1"
```

I tried to run this php file that sends an email with a php class once receive these two parameters. But seems cron is not recognizing this command. I wonder where is the mistake here? or ways that I can run this in commandline and troubleshoot it will also be really helpful!

**File runs perfectly in browser with exactly same url string.**

I also tried another variation:

```
38  17  5   11  *       root    /usr/bin/sudo -u _www /usr/bin/curl -sS "http://123.com/index.php?email=1&test=1"
```

I have tried to do these crul command in commandline for testing :

```
curl "http://123.com/index.php?email=1&test=1"
```

and

```
curl "http://123.com/index.php?email=1\&test=1"
```

#### UPDATE

Now I tried this

```
echo "TEST" >> $CRONLOG
/usr/bin/sudo -u _www /usr/bin/curl -sS "http://123.com/index.php?email=1&test=1" >> $CRONLOG
```

#### UPDATE

the solution provided by fedorqui of escaping & worked well in my test file, so something else is wrong with my orignal file. Investigating

#### FINAL UPDATE

It came out that our authentication file that is included using php in the php file prevent the php file from going further! So its not (just) a syntax but a mix of forgetting escape `&` + auth file included.

Comment: What if you escape the `&`? `http://123.com/index.php?email=1\&test=1"`

Comment: Err in your updated answer you have `/&`, whereas I said `\&`. Which one did you try?

Comment: Ok! Mmmm to be on the safe side I would move this code to a script and call the script in the crontab. There must be some issue with escaping characters, etc. Also, did you check the logs from cron? Any traces?

Comment: @fedorqui I tried in a test file, the / escap worked! but not in my original file. I think there maybe something more complex going on in that file could cause this! Investigating!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in the comments, the `&` character has a special meaning, so to make it be treated as literal you need to escape it.

from

```
38 17 5 11 * root ... curl -sS "http:// ... email=1&test=1"
```

to

```
38 17 5 11 * root ... curl -sS "http:// ... email=1\&test=1"
                                                   ^
```